# Bootstrap Carousel Didn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weirdo question, I just wanted to use carousel by using bootstrap. I include bootstrap.js into my code then i used Log Console Javascript,
there was some error codes
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Then i changed all 'on' method into 'bind'

but now the whole links (  tag) didn't work, does anyone could solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include jquery javascript file

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js" />
   </head>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery.js what version of jquery should i use ?

Comment: @YoshuaJooBin The `on` method is from v1.7+, so that's your baseline. However, the latest iteration of Bootstrap (2.2) was developed on v1.8.1, so depending on whether they leveraged anything new to that version, you might have to use that as your minimum.